# What would be needed to scientifically be able to stand on cloud?

Tags: science-fiction, physics, xenobiology, chemistry, clouds

Inspired from [people walking on water](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-DZ0f0_NCA) using cornstarch plus myths such as monkey king, several gods in heaven/celestial palace, and other fiction works.

(image from Dragon Ball by Akira Toriyama)
[image]

I want to know what would enable a person to stand on a cloud, be it via chemical or physical means.

(visual trick or optical illusion that just standing on platforms such as flying/air ship or levitate on air and use or surrounded by some kind of fog or smoke rather than really standing or the platforms supported on cloud by physical or chemical means is not an answer i search for, sorry, need to add it otherwise it may get out of hand, but i apreciate the answer nonetheless, its my fault for not add it quicker.)

(I use science fiction tag because it may not possible for science-based answer, but much appreciate if it really possible in real science)

Comment: Do you accept "a pole long enough to reach the clouds with a platform on top of it" as an answer?

Comment: @TheDyingOfLight no, i preffer a real cloud (whatever the cloud material is made of) rather than visual trickery or optical illusion that it stand on cloud, unless the platform can make the person can stand on cloud without ground support like pole, something like aerogel on top of cloud for example, also flying ship actually out of the solution if it just mean for visual trick.

Comment: Cheat answer: a small quadcopter with a larger aerogel platform and a fog generator.  Not actually a cloud, but could look like one.

Comment: Quite apart from the reasons given in the answers, the most practical reason that you can't stand "on" a cloud is that clouds don't have distinct boundaries.  That they appear to is merely an artifact of seeing them from a considerable distance.  If you've ever flown a small plane (and have an instrument rating), you'll have seen that there's a transition zone of - oh, something on the order of 100 yards/meters between clear air and cloud.  (Commercial jets travel too fast to really notice this.)

Comment: @jamesqf can you explain more? i kinda confuse what you mean? and what the relation with standing on cloud and the cloud dont have distinct boundaries?

Comment: @Li Jun: Think of standing on the ground.  There's a distinct boundary (on the human scale - maybe a few millimeters) between ground and air.  But with clouds, the boundary between cloud and clear air is a gradual transition extending over tens or hundreds of meters, so there's no definite place where a human-sized object can be said to be "on" the cloud.

Comment: @jamesqf so from what i get you mean technically the person still standing in a mix of air and cloud, or you mean the cloud keep moving/change shape not stay in place/shape because of the air?

Comment: @Li Jun: No.  Clouds are water droplets (or ice particles) suspended in air.  The transition between "air with no droplets" and "air with so many droplets that you can't see through it" is gradual.  Even when flying through your basic fluffy cumulus cloud, there's a good bit more air than droplets, since you can easily see your wingtips.  Try doing an image search on something like "flying through clouds".  Or have you ever walked in fog?  Fog's just a cloud on the ground.

Answer (score 9):

Short boring answer: nope.

Even a really, really dense gas ([tungsten hexafluoride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tungsten_hexafluoride), 12.4g/l at room temperature... actual tungsten gas might be denser, but it would be at a hazardous 6203K) is much less dense than the lightest solids (solid hydrogen, 86g/l, at a chilly 14K or lithium, 534g/l at room temperature). You could cheat by using carefully structured solids like aerogels (as low as 1.1g/l) in a dense atmosphere but aerogels are only low density because they are mostly made of air. Therefore any cloud-trapeze aid using aerogels is basically equivalent to making a lighter-than-air balloon, so you may as well do that instead.

So slightly longer but no less boring answer: no, unless you use something lighter than air to stand on.

You could *look* like you were standing on cloud though, with a bit of theatrical cunning, and perhaps a lower gravitational field. In the same way that you can have a boat made of materials that are denser than water (eg. iron, concrete, etc) it is possible to make an object that is bouyant enough to float on a layer of sufficiently dense gas. It is still possible to sink such a boat if the dense gas gets in over the side, perhaps because you overloaded it. Here's a nice example: [foil boat floating in sulphur hexafluoride](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1PJTq2xQiQ0). Now, I'm too lazy to do the actual calculations for you, but in *theory* you might be able to float a suitably sealed, suitably large boat made out of something very light (like expanded polystyrene foam or indeed aerogel), float it on a layer of super-dense gas, and then stand on it. Very carefully pour a layer of cloud, perhaps using a conventional dry-ice smoke generator, and tada! Possibly. Earth's gravity is probably far too high for this trick, but it might well be possible on other worlds.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [aerogels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerogel) to imitate a cloud.

> Aerogel is a synthetic porous ultralight material derived from a gel, in which the liquid component for the gel has been replaced with a gas. The result is a solid with extremely low density and extremely low thermal conductivity.

Being extremely low dense, aerogel can be easily lifted to look like it is floating, and it can withstand quite some load, see the image below, where a brick weighing 2.5 kg is supported by 2 g of aerogel.

[image: brick on aerogel]

Just make sure that no concentrated load is applied, since aerogel crumbles easily once damaged. So, if you walk on aerogel, no heels!

To sustain a load you would probably need some mean of lifting the aerogel, though.

Comment: what happen if the aerogel mix in or on  the cloud?

Comment: If you just want to _look_ like you're standing on clouds, why not just get a dry ice smoke generator? Much more convenient, much lower health risk.

Comment: @LiJun You couldn't use this approach to float on cloud. Aerogels are denser than air. If you were willing to make an artificial lighter-than-air objects to stand on in the clouds, just use a balloon instead.

Comment: When you say that aerogels float, you mean on water and not air, correct?

Comment: @NuclearWang, I better rephrase that

Comment: well polyimide reinforced silica aerogel used by nasa can support the concentrated load of a car on a blanket, so I assume they are perfecting ways to make it more durable.

Answer (score 4):

Clouds have a charge. Normally, the top part of the cloud has excessive positive charge, while the bottom accumulate a negative charge.

[Lightning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning) is produced when the two balance out temporarily.

So, what you can try doing is

1. Establish some clouds / physical conditions which have charge accumulation in such a manner (top surface positively charged)
2. Build a suit which can somehow accumulate this +ve charge
3. Rely on electromagnetic repulsion due to the (+ve cloud) (+ve suit) charges, to appear to walk/ balance out the gravity force.

Comment: In the OP's photo, the cloud-pilot *does* have his/her hair on end. What would keep those charged cloud-droplets from moving away?

Comment: 4.  Hope you don't get a first-hand up-close opportunity to study [blue jets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper-atmospheric_lightning#Jets).

Comment: @glen_geek this answer is science-fiction, not science-based :) In OP's photo, that hair on the end is probably to depict hair being blown due to wind when moving..

Answer (score 3):

I think that it is impossible to stand on a cloud in the sense of having your weight supported by a cloud.

But possible someone could hover in the air in standing posture with their feet near the  upper border of a cloud and their head clearly above the upper border of the cloud.  Thus they could look like they were standing on the cloud.  And possibly they might use a fog machine to give the cloud an artificially sharp upper border where they seem to be  "standing" on it.

So presumably they would be hovering by wearing an anti gravity belt, or possibly a spaceship hovering far above using anti gravity would be supporting them with a tractor beam - and they would be hoping that the tractor beam doesn't have a power failure.

Or maybe, and even less plausibly, they would have some sort of psychic ability to levitate.

Answer (score 2):

You generally can't stand on a gas because it is a fluid and you're more dense than it - so it goes around you as you sink into it. For reference, we are more than 1,000x denser than regular, breathable air at sea level on a warm day.

The obvious solution is to use a gas that is denser than you. But here we have a problem. To have a really dense gas, we should either use heavier elements or increase pressure and temperature. Heavier elements are out of question - we wouldn't float on a 1 atm cloud of iron (and we'd vaporize if we stayed on it long enough anyway). As for regular air, we could increase pressure until it is denser than 1g/cm<sup>3</sup>, but at room temperature it would be liquid. If we heat it up to be a gas again, well... It won't be comfortable on your feet. Also I don't have the charts on me now but it might be a cloud of plasma rather than a cloud of proper gas.

Alternatively, since you used [science-fiction](/questions/tagged/science-fiction) instrad of [science-based](/questions/tagged/science-based) or [hard-science](/questions/tagged/hard-science), you could remove some Higgs bosons from your body to become less dende than a cloud. But even then you would be walking on air, not on the clouds - clouds are up there in the sky because they are less dense than the air down here.

Comment: *"clouds are up there in the sky because they are less dense than the air down here"* Not really. Clouds start to form when the local air temperature drops below the local dew point for the local relative humidity of the air. They generally keep growing upwards until the local relative humidity drops too far to sustain cloud formation. Depending on local characteristics they'll either precipitate in some form (rain, hail, snow, ...), or not. Clouds don't form because they are "less dense" than air elsewhere. Updrafts, wind, etc., complicate this somewhat, but that's still the gist of it.

Comment: @aCVn I didn't say they form in great altitudes because they are less dense, I said they stay there because of that.

Answer (score 1):

You could fool viewers on the ground with a space elevator that didn’t go all the way to the ground but instead stopped at cloud layer. If the castle produced its own mist cloud underneath, from the ground, it looks like a tall tower that sticks out into space with nothing holding it up except clouds.

Answer (score 1):

Little-known science fact: It's actually possible to have a gas that's denser than water at room temperature. Well, almost. At the pressure required, it'll technically be a supercritical fluid, which will act like a gas in many ways.

Specifically, you'll want to use supercritical xenon. At something like 100 atmospheres of pressure, xenon actually becomes denser than water, as demonstrated in [this Cody's Lab video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AsP4yMY-a6U).

Caveats:

- Pure water won't actually float on this, as the xenon will dissolve into it and form a clathrate, causing it to freeze. Adding alcohol to the water, though, will prevent this from happening, so you could have floating lakes of vodka.
- This environment will be quite hostile to humans, since xenon is a powerful anaesthetic. Inhaling supercritical xenon will lead to unconsciousness almost instantly, and likely to death shortly thereafter. Also, I wouldn't be surprised if xenon at this pressure can dissolve through the skin.
- You'll also need to be careful about decompression sickness when returning from this environment, if you're not wearing an atmospheric-pressure diving suit (i.e. the kind made of rigid materials that's essentially a wearable submarine, which keeps the pressure inside at a comfortable 1 atmosphere).

With that in mind, I think it should be possible for a human to survive at least temporarily in supercritical xenon, provided that they have a SCUBA mask, a tank of [heliox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heliox) (a mix of helium and a little oxygen, because the nitrogen in air becomes toxic at these pressures), and some kind of completely-sealed (but not necessarily rigid) diving suit.

And with this gear, you'd be able to float on a cloud in this environment in exactly the same way a deep-sea diver can float on any cloud of oceanic debris.

Comment: I dunno, gas denser than water is pretty neat... but we can't walk on water (supernatural means excluded).  One could float inside your supercritical gas, but not really stand on it - especially not with the visual distinction OP seems to be looking for.

Comment: @Megha Maybe not, but this is about the closest you're going to get without wires or balloons.